# how to demux from flv to vp8(ivf format)? how to demux from webm to vp8?

Tags: webm, vp8

I want to demux from flv to vp8.

I can get lots of webm sources, but I don't know how I can demux from webm to vp8.

What option should I use with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to demux the VP8 stream from a WebM video to an [IVF file](http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=IVF) using FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i WEBM_INPUT.webm -vcodec copy -an -f ivf VP8_OUTPUT.ivf
```

As far as I know IVF is the closest you can get to raw VP8.